# Mutate(across(all_of())) Custom Function Error

Tags: r

**df1:**

```
library(caret)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

#Vectors
a = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
c = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
d = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
e = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)

#df1
df1 = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

**Column Name Vector, Proportions of variables in columns, Custom Function for encoding values <30% as "Rare"**

```
#Col Name Vector
cols <- c("a", "b", "c")

#Col Proportions
freq = prop.table(table(unlist(df1[cols])))
make_rare = names(freq)[freq< 0.3]

#Functions
#Rare label
rare_label <- function(x,cv){
  replace(x, x %in% cv, "Rare")
}
```

**Magrittr Pipe:**

```
#Pipeline
df1 <- df1 %>%
  #Rare Label Encoding
  mutate(d = rare_label(d,make_rare)) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(cols), rare_label(cv=make_rare)))
```

**My question is why does the last mutate(across(all_of())) not work but the mutate above it does using the same function?**

Looking to keep code in this format (custom function) as I want to create a "library" of functions I can call for this type of work.

**Output:**

```
a    b    c    d    e
aa   aa   aa   aa   1
bb   bb   bb   bb   0
Rare Rare Rare Rare 1
aa   aa   aa   aa   0
aa   aa   aa   aa   0
aa   aa   aa   aa   0
bb   bb   bb   bb   1
Rare Rare Rare Rare 1
bb   bb   bb   bb   1
bb   bb   bb   bb   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rare_label` needs two arguments, `x` and `cv`. In the `across` call, you don't provide the `x` argument. You can use your function with `across` e.g. in this way:

```
library(dplyr)

#Vectors
a = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
c = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
d = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "cc", "bb", "bb") 
e = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)

#df1
df1 = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)

#Col Name Vector
cols <- c("a", "b", "c")

#Col Proportions
freq = prop.table(table(unlist(df1[cols])))
make_rare = names(freq)[freq< 0.3]

#Functions
#Rare label
rare_label <- function(x,cv){
  replace(x, x %in% cv, "Rare")
}

#Pipeline
df1 <- df1 %>%
  #Rare Label Encoding
  mutate(d = rare_label(d,make_rare)) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(cols), ~rare_label(x = .x, cv=make_rare)))
 df1
      a    b    c    d e
1    aa   aa   aa   aa 1
2    bb   bb   bb   bb 0
3  Rare Rare Rare Rare 1
4    aa   aa   aa   aa 0
5    aa   aa   aa   aa 0
6    aa   aa   aa   aa 0
7    bb   bb   bb   bb 1
8  Rare Rare Rare Rare 1
9    bb   bb   bb   bb 1
10   bb   bb   bb   bb 1
```

In `across`, you have 3 possibilities how to use a function:

- if the first argument of the function is where your input vector goes into (and possible other arguments don't need to be set), you can just use the name of the function, e.g. `data %>% mutate(across(everything(), log))`
- if the first argument of the function is where your input vector goes into and you want to specify other arguments, you can just list this arguments after the function name, e.g. `data %>% mutate(across(everything(), log, base = 10))`
- you can use `purrr` style formulas to make anonymous functions; you can read `~log(.x)` as "apply `log` to `.x` where `.x` is the argument provided to the anonymous function. It is equal to `function(.x) {log(.x)}`, `.x` is chosen as name to not get in naming conflicts, you could also use another variable name. Here with the application in `mutate`, `.x` is the column passed to `log`, e.g. in `data %>% mutate(across(column_1, ~log(.x)))` `.x` are the values/vector of `column_1`. If you select several columns in `across`, `log` is applied column-wise, so `.x` are the values of the respective column to which `log` is applied to, e.g. `data %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~log(.x)))`

Comment: Could you explain or provide me an article showing what ~rare_label(x = .x does (the "~" and ".x")?

Comment: Do my explanations help? I feel I've made it a bit too complicated.